# PHP how to convert dd/mm/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert convert dd/mm/yy to yyyy-mm-dd. After i researched several methods and I found this.

```
$var = '20/01/2021'; 
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var); 
$show_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

It works fine with result `2021-01-20`.
However, my input was two digit yy only which is `20/01/21` and the result became `2020-01-21`.

Comment: Check out the DateTime class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an ambigous date like you have it is better to use the `DateTime` class as you can set the input format. See the following example from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$var = '20/01/21'; 

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $var); // "d/m/y" corresponds to the input format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //outputs 2021-01-20
```